# AWS EC2 Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS Upgrade problems

Tags: upgrade, amazon-ec2, aws

I have an AWS EC2 instance that I am running a website on and I am running into issues while upgrading it.

Here are the steps I have tried:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
```

[image]

After the first part everything looked good and than I proceeded:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

And then we error out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-_29ga8ky/bionic", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-_29ga8ky/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 238, in main
    if app.run():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-_29ga8ky/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 2072, in run
    return self.fullUpgrade()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-_29ga8ky/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1981, in fullUpgrade
    if not self.askDistUpgrade():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-_29ga8ky/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1153, in askDistUpgrade
    changes = self.calcDistUpgrade()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-_29ga8ky/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1120, in calcDistUpgrade
    if not self.cache.installTasks(self.tasks):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-_29ga8ky/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeCache.py", line 856, in installTasks
    pkg.mark_install()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/package.py", line 1356, in mark_install
    fixer.resolve(True)
SystemError: E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 497, in add_to_existing
    self.write(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 450, in write
    block = f.read(1048576)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-_29ga8ky/bionic", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-_29ga8ky/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 238, in main
    if app.run():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-_29ga8ky/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 2072, in run
    return self.fullUpgrade()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-_29ga8ky/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1981, in fullUpgrade
    if not self.askDistUpgrade():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-_29ga8ky/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1153, in askDistUpgrade
    changes = self.calcDistUpgrade()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-_29ga8ky/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1120, in calcDistUpgrade
    if not self.cache.installTasks(self.tasks):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-_29ga8ky/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeCache.py", line 856, in installTasks
    pkg.mark_install()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/package.py", line 1356, in mark_install
    fixer.resolve(True)
SystemError: E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
=== Command terminated with exit status 1 (Thu Oct 22 03:03:11 2020) ===
```

After looking through the errors more I think this is where my issue is, but I am still stuck and not sure what to do from here:

```
Reinst Failed because of python3-zope.interface:amd64  MarkKeep python3-twisted [ amd64 ]
```

Comment: `sudo apt upgrade` only upgrades packages which don't have dependencies on other packages that need installed. You therefore have an 'incomplete' system to start with the distribution upgrades. Start by doing `sudo apt dist-upgrade` to get to the full updated system set, then focus on considering to do the `sudo do-release-upgrade`

Comment: SO I ran the sudo apt-dist-upgrade and it looks like it didnt change anything: https://pastebin.com/95QVPBtM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up having to uninstall `python3` and `python-certbot-nginx` then I was able to go ahead with my install.

Answer (score 1):

I think the key point is `E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages`---what is the output if you run `apt-get -f install` (no other arguments).

If you get no output, what is the output of `apt-mark showhold`? If there is any output from this second command, try to `apt-mark unhold` each package and then run `apt-get update` then `apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Comment: For the apt-get -f install here is the output: https://pastebin.com/1gqxyLG8

Comment: @Mike Jones Sorry, by "no output" I really meant if it did anything. What happens when you do the next part of the answer?

Comment: no worries. The apt-mark showhold returned nothing.